# What are the differences between ngx-translate and ngx-i18next

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization, i18next, ngx-translate

While `ngx-i18next` is a wrapper on `i18next` I wonder in particular what are the translation-related differences between `ngx-translate` and `i18next`.

Answer (score 0):

i18next is non-angular exclusiv -> so anytime you stop using angular (or do nodejs,...) you can use i18next there too

beside that rather sure both get the job done.

i18next has one additional benefit (beside the huge ecosystem https://www.i18next.com/supported-frameworks.html -> learn once - translate everywhere): it comes with a translation management tier: https://locize.com so you do not only get code instrumentation but also a solution for your translators, project managers,...